# Insert datagrid values into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I'm trying to insert some runtime generated datagridview values into a SQL Server table.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnTrimitebon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTrimitebon.Click
    functii.adaugabonmagazie()
    Dim dvgPieseCumparate As New DataGridView
    Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim dt As DataTable = functii.piesecumparate(txtFpo.Text)
    dvgPieseCumparate.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    dvgPieseCumparate.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    dvgPieseCumparate.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    dvgPieseCumparate.AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
    dvgPieseCumparate.AutoSizeColumnsMode =
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
    dvgPieseCumparate.DataSource = dt
    dvgPieseCumparate.Refresh()
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234"
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[SC Vermorel SRL$MagLines]
          ([RPO]
          ,[FPO]
          ,[Articol]
          ,[Description]
          ,[QtyperPiesa]
          ,[QtyTotal]
          ,[Indice])
    VALUES
          (@RPO
          ,@FPO
          ,@Articol
          ,@Description,
          ,@QtyperPiesa
          ,@QtyTotal
          ,@Indice)"
        command.Parameters.Add("@RPO", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@FPO", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Articol", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@QtyperPiesa", SqlDbType.Int)
        command.Parameters.Add("@QtyTotal", SqlDbType.Int)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Indice", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        con.Open()
        command.Connection = con
        For i As Integer = 0 To dvgPieseCumparate.Rows.Count - 1
            command.Parameters(0).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            command.Parameters(1).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            command.Parameters(2).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            command.Parameters(3).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            command.Parameters(4).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            command.Parameters(5).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
            command.Parameters(6).Value = dvgPieseCumparate.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Also the table definition from SSMS:

[image: table definition]

If I generate the dgv and put it and display it on a form its ok, but when I try to add its values in the sql table, no error, but no values added also.

[image: datagridview]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `,@Description,` is probably causing the failure.

Comment: How is that, Jinx? Can you be more specific. Thank you.

Comment: Leading comma is what I spotted. Should be `,@Description` keeping in line with your other parameters. You've basically done: `...,@Description,,@QtyperPiesa...`

Comment: It seems that datagridview isn't populating at runtime, it must in the on_load trigger of a form to populate. I've put some msgboxes after each operation and it says datagrid has 0 rows, although its datasource, the dt datable, says that it has rows.

Comment: Do you need the DGV to update or could you loop through the DataTable instead? You could look at a `BindingSource` instead. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx) may help.